# ImportError: No module named apiclient.errors

Tags: python, google-api

for anyone using Google API´s and wanting to implement exponential backoff like in the docs:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/errors#backoff

and getting following Error:

```
ImportError: No module named apiclient.errors
```

Answer (score 0):

there´s an easy fix which I want to let you know. Instead of using the library `apiclient` you have to use and import `googleapiclient` (which is the successor library) like :

```
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
```

there you go, I hope it helps some people out there.